# How to automate EF 4.3 Code-First SQL Schema Migration Script using MSBuild Task

Tags: entity-framework, msbuild-task, entity-framework-migrations

For the background context, we are using EF 4.3.1 code-first and migrations in MVC 3 application. In the past, we have done dev and staging deployments manually but now we are trying to automate the process to create dev and staging build using MSBUILD Tasks and TFS as source control.

My questions relates to above context as how can we generate sql migration script using EF migrations powershell commands "Update-Database -verbose -script" in MSBUILD tasks.

Is there any way to use native EF 4.3.1 migration commands in MSBUILD task to automate differential sql script generation ?

Thanks in advance for your inputs.

Comment: What's wrong with using PowerShell with MSBuild?

Comment: I agree with @tzerb. MSBuild is simply a declartive workflow engine. You can call out to any tool you need.

Comment: @tzerb, well we already have build projects for dev/ staging / production environments and we can execute batch file to kickoff the build which is working fine. what i'm after is how to use EF migrations powershell commands in msbuild project file so that script generation can be handled by msbuild project.

Comment: @PreetSangha, I agree with you that we can call out any other tool but as we are not much experienced working with build projects it's not exactly clear to us as how to script it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should just call powershell: See [Using Powershell scripts from MSBuild, Scheduled Tasks, etc](http://blog.brianhartsock.com/2009/10/20/using-powershell-scripts-from-msbuild-scheduled-tasks-etc/)

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="powershell.exe -command &quot;&amp; {.\Register-myscript.ps1 &apos;$(TargetPath)&apos;}&quot;" />
</Target>
```

Comment: let me test it out. i'll get back to you on this.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it just shows how to call PowerShell to execute some unrelated command.
How does this help call the Update-Database migration command?

Answer (score 0):

You can have an MSBuild Task running the Migrate.exe as explained here [How to run Entity Framework Migrations using MSBuild and Migrate.exe](http://blog.brianhartsock.com/2009/10/20/using-powershell-scripts-from-msbuild-scheduled-tasks-etc/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version of the msbuild task. It copies migrate.exe from the tools folder of EF 6 into the build directory. In order for this to work all the paths are absolute.

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
<copy SourceFiles="$(SolutionDir)packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\migrate.exe" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)" />
<exec Command="$(TargetDir)migrate.exe *YourData.dll* Configuration /startUpDirectory:$(TargetDir) /startUpConfigurationFile:$(TargetDir)WebStart.NET.dll.config /verbose"/>
</Target>
```